# How to Combine Two or more parametrised Monos Webflux Best practice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

So I am calling a service "ServiceA" that makes an external call via webclient, that returns a mono,
Then I would like to call another service "serviceB" that also makes a similar external call, this time passing some data from
"serviceA" mono and perhaps some other external parameter.

```
Mono<ResponseA> responseAmono = serviceA.getdataA("some parameter");
Mono<ResponseB> responseBmono = serviceB.getdataB("data from responseAmono", "some parameter")
```

Currently I have this implementation.

```
responseAmono
        .doOnSuccess(data -> {
            if (data.field == true) {
                serviceB.getdataB(data, "some parameter");
            }
        })
        .subscribe(x -> {}, e -> sout("serviceA Subscription Error! "+ e.getMessage()));
```

But I faced challenges with thread pool, had to increase pendingAcquireQueue from a max of 1000 connections, because of `PoolAcquirePendingLimitException`

So, what is the best strategy to combine these two monos putting a good performance i.e `>4000 tps` in mind?.

And separation of concerns when invoking the inner mono "serviceB".

Note. I subscription is also implemented on serviceB.

Answer (score 3):

`doOnSuccess()` should only be called for synchronous side-effects, not reactive operations. If you're essentially blocking inside a `doOnSuccess()` call, this is likely why you're running into threading issues.

Instead, `flatMap()` would be a much better choice as that keeps everything reactive. If you still want to return the result of service A and ignore the result from service B, you can do that similarly to the below:

```
responseAmono
    .flatMap(data -> {
        if (data.field == true) {
            return serviceB.getdataB(data, "some parameter").thenReturn(data);
        }
        else {
            return Mono.just(data);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Michael Berry, let me refactor and do some benchmark tests. will respond.